# Changing the auto-hibernate settings on a AWS Cloud9 EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

While setting up the AWS Cloud9 EC2 instance, I selected 30 mins for auto-hibernation. I would like to change this to **Never**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On an EC2 environment, go to AWS Cloud9 > Preferences > (in the Preferences tab) Project Settings > scroll down to Stop my environment (or click EC2 Instance in Project Settings section on the sidebar)

Comment: Are there some configuration file to hardcore this parameter?

Comment: The value for this is machine-specific and is set in the `~/.c9/autoshutdown-configuration` file.

Comment: This answer is no-longer valid and @user26270 answer below should be the correct answer

Answer (score 20):

This may have changed since the previous answer. I was looking for exactly this, and didn't see any Preferences Tab in the main Cloud9 page. But I did find it in the project settings->EC2 Instance

[image: Screenshot of the relevant UI pieces]

Comment: This is now the correct answer. Previous correct answer no longer applies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This changed again, and the two previous answers no longer work.
[image]