# How can I change the automatic hibernation time for AWS Cloud9 or shut it down manually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

When I'm using AWS Cloud9, an EC2 instance is running in the background hosting it. By default, the EC2 instance hibernates after 30m, but sometimes I just want to use the IDE for 2 minutes and not have the EC2 instance running for 30m afterwards. Can I reduce the threshold for hibernation further or hibernate the EC2 instance manually?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have Cloud9 running on its own on-demand EC2 instance (the default setting during setup), you can find the EC2 instance backing it in your EC2 management console and shut down the instance manually when you're done with it.

Comment: The Hibernate Instance option is greyed out in the EC2 console for me.

Comment: I don't think you can change the threshold for hibernation besides the preset values, but here's how to change the values to one of the preset values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58857892/1413201